# What prevents this third-order QED scattering from having a non-zero amplitude?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, feynman-diagrams

I have learned that in the Dyson-Wick expansion of the QED scattering operator

$$
S=e^{-i\int_{t_i}^{t_f}H\mathrm{d}t}
$$

with the QED interaction Lagrangian

$$
H=e\bar\psi\gamma^\mu A_\mu\psi
$$

in the limits $t_i\to-\infty$, $t_f\to\infty$, 
the first-order and third-order terms all vanish. For the first-order terms (single-vertex Feynman diagrams) this seems clear to me, since they correspond to an $e^-e^+$ pair that annihilates into a real photon, which is prevented by energy-momentum conservation at the single vertex.

The same argument holds for many third-order diagrams.

However, there are also three-order diagrams where I cannot see why their amplitudes should vanish, for example this one:

[image]

Here, time flows from left to right.

If I understand it correctly, this diagram corresponds to the term (where $\mathcal N$ means the normal ordering "operator"):

$$
\int\int\int dx_1dx_2dx_3 \,\mathcal N\left\{ (\overline\psi^-\gamma^\mu {A_\mu}^-\psi^+)_{x_3}, (\overline\psi^-\gamma^\nu {A_\nu}^+\psi^-)_{x_2}, (\overline\psi^+\gamma^\rho {A_\rho}^-\psi^+)_{x_1}\right\}
$$

The process is

- destruction of real $e^+e^-$ pair and creation of virtual photon at the (left-most) point $x_1$.
- destruction of the virtual photon and creation of a virtual electron and a real positron at the (middle) point $x_2$.
- destruction of the virtual electron and creation of an electron-photon pair at the (right-most) point $x_3$.

I don't see why this process should have a zero amplitude. I tried to evaluate it and did not see a delta function that prevents it (like in energy-momentum conservation).

What prevents this process from being physical, i.e. from having a non-zero amplitude?

Comment: Do you remember Furry theorem? Note that it works only for the sum of the diagrams not for individual ones.

Comment: @OON: Furry's theorem is usually stated as "diagrams with a fermion loop and an odd number of external photon legs vanish". It's not immediate to see how to apply it to this diagram.

Comment: Bass, why do you *think* this diagram should vanish? It just looks like an $e^+ +e ^-\to e^+ + e^-$ concatenated with a bremsstrahlung diagram, and neither of those vanish. That the third-order contributions *in total* vanish doesn't mean the individual diagrams vanish - it might just destructively interfere with another third-order diagram.

Comment: @ACuriousMind Yeah, that's true. I would still look at its sum with a similar diagram for the same process with not electron but positron radiating.

Comment: @ACuriousMind In the lecture notes I'm reading, the professor explained that third-order terms vanish (most likely in the sense of "vanish as a sum because of interference"), and he went on to describe some examples of third-order terms that vanish because of off-shell real particles. Let's wait and see, maybe someone knows it for certain. Thanks.

Comment: Your s-channel diagram and all the others where the photon is emitted from another leg, as well as all the t-channel diagrams definitively have a non-zero contribution. $e^+e^-\to e^+e^-\gamma$ was quite important to know at LEP (including a $Z^0$ exchange as well a photon), and a great deal of work has been poured into computing the cross-sections. The classic reference is Anthony C. Hearn, P. K. Kuo, and D. R. Yennie. Radiative corrections to an electron-positron scattering experiment. Phys. Rev., 187:1950–1963, Nov 1969.

Comment: Hi Bass. Are you reading Student Friendly Quantum Field Theory by Klauber? On page 256 he says the Dyson term " $S^{(3)}$ plays no role in QED and can be ignored". I couldn't see why either and was confused. Having read the answers to your question I wonder if this is just a mistake in the book.

Comment: It was a mistake. I've just checked and he issued an errata doc!

Answer (score 6):

Not sure where and how you got your magnificent misimpression that your diagram vanishes.

Of course it does not: it is one of the 8 tree diagrams [image: hard brem]
of ***hard bremsstrahlung***, e.g. from S M Swanson, *Phys Rev* **154** (1967) 1601, all related to each other by suitable crossings and permutations of external momenta. They yield the standard O(*α<sup>3</sup>*) cross section for the process.

The amp and its line-perm brethren are physical indeed. An awful amount of actual experimental physics relies on it, and it has an elegant form, cf. section 3 of [Berends & Kleiss](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0550321383905588). There is no good reason it should vanish.